# Metaprogramming with std::is_same

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to do something like the following that compiles without template specialization?

```
template <class T> 
class A {
public:
    #if std::is_same<T, int>
        void has_int() { }
    #elif std::is_same<T, char>
        void has_char() { }
    #endif
};
A<int> a; a.has_int();
A<char> b; b.has_char();
```

Comment: You can't mix preprocessor statements with the c++ compiler's template instantiation.

Comment: you mean `A<char> b`, right?

Comment: related: [c++ class template specialization, without having to reimplement everything](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25486033/3953764)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. Make the function templates and then conditionaly enable them using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> 
class A {
public:

  template<typename U = T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,int>::value>::type
  has_int() {}

  template<typename U = T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U,char>::value>::type
  has_char() {}
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    a.has_int();   // OK
    // a.has_char();  // error
}
```

The solution from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27504322/947836) might not be feasible if the class is big and has got many functions that need to regardless of `T`. But you can solve this by inheriting from another class that is used only for these special methods. Then, you can specialize that base class only.

In C++14, there are convenient type aliases so the syntax can become:

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, int>::value>
```

And C++17, even shorter:

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, int>>
```

Comment: you could add that in C++14 you can write `std:::enable_if_t` and in C++17 even `std::is_same_v` in order to get rid of the `typename ... ::type` and `::value` verbosity.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, with template specialization :

```
template <class T> 
class A;

template <> 
class A<int>
{
    void had_int(){}
};

template <> 
class A<char>
{
    void had_char(){}
};
```

Comment: Is there any way without rewriting the same code twice?

Comment: You can introduce new class member declarations with template specialization? That's something new for me.

Comment: @ZeroCool Maybe in the future you can: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Static-If-I-Had-a-Hammer

Comment: @ZeroCool It is not the same code twice. You are implementing different behavior when a template argument is different.

Comment: @BЈовић But presumably those classes have more members that would be the same.

Comment: @5gon12eder Static if was rejected in the committee. Haven't heard of any effort to bring it back.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I don't see more members in the question. Anyway, you could add another class that uses this template.

Comment: @BЈовић Because it's a reduced example. If he had posted the code with additional members, people would have complained about a non-minimal example. And yes, you can do class splits to work around this issue, but it's a workaround and can get rather complicated.

Comment: @BЈовић Thanks for proposal. Actually original class is enormous which I agree is not good design anyway. Splitting it and template specializing it would create more code than it is already needed.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I didn't know that.  My state of knowledge was that it was postponed for later decision.  Honestly, I'm not too sad about that decision, I must say…

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, as long as it has the same number of template parameters a specialization can be totally different from the primary template ... although that would usually be a bad idea to do :)